# handle start requests actions in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am facing weird behavior when I am yielding the requests, Ideally each request will be yielded after 6 seconds, but what is actually happening is that after 60 (6*10) seconds all requests are made at once, I was able to fix this by `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=1`.

```
import scrapy
import time
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Test'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            time.sleep(6)
            url = "http://www.example.com"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

If i set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=3` it will wait 18 seconds to yield 3 requests then move to the next 3 (wait 18 sec and then yield) and so on. (I am using `time.sleep(6)` to replace a function I have that takes about that much time to do). How can I force it yield the request (like a regular generator)

Comment: Interesting, there is usually no heavy processing in `start_requests`, your use case is rather uncommon. It may be worth posting an enhancement request in the Scrapy issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting in order to make delay between requests.

```
import scrapy
import time
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Test'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    custom_settings = {
        "DOWNLOAD_DELAY": 6,
        "RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY": False 
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        for _ in range(10):
            url = "http://www.example.com"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url,callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self,response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

This code do following:
As result of `start_requests` method - spider will add 10 requests to scrapy scheduler queue .(It doesn't mean that scrapy immediately execute 10 requests).


Using `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and `RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY` settings:
Scrapy downloader get request from scheduler queue and send it to your website.

 When response received -> callback method called. 
 This process repeats each 6 seconds (As defined in `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` setting)

Comment: I realize this,but I already mentioned in my question that `time.sleep()` is simply there to represent another function that takes 5-7 seconds to complete so it is not really a download delay I am trying to use

Comment: Also, you have to remember Scrapy is ran asynchronously.